# Data getting lost while passing from controller to view in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In one of my controller, I'm passing the result obtained from an Eloquent query to a view. But no matter how I pass the result to the view, I'm not getting the result in the view.

The controller:

```
class ProductCategoriesController extends BaseController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Add location hinting for views
        View::addNamespace('product-categories', app_path() . "/MyVendor/ProductsManager/Views/admin/product-categories");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $categories = ProductCategory::all();

        return View::make('product-categories::index')
                    ->with('title', 'All Product Categories')
                    ->with('categories', $categories);
    }

    ...
}
```

If I view the `dd` the value of `$categories` inside the `index` controller, I get the proper Eloquent collection, like following:

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[655]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 =>
         object(MyVendor\ProductsManager\Models\ProductCategory)[653]
          protected 'table' => string 'product_categories' (length=18)
          protected 'guarded' => ...
```

But if I `dd` the value of `$categories` inside the `index` view, I get an empty Eloquent collection, like following:

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[655]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => null
```

I am doing similar approach in other controllers and they work fine. I don't know what the problem with this controller is. I have been using Laravel for quite some time now and never had this problem before. Maybe I'm missing something, or there's something wrong with the recent package updates. Whatever it is, it's driving me crazy. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

P.S. I'm using `Laravel Framework version 4.2.6`

Comment: Can you post your view and model code too?

Comment: Maybe you call `View::composer` with the same variable name, what if you rename `categories` to something else?

Comment: You may have some other global bindings to this view with this name. Rename binding.

Comment: have you tried `View::make('product-categories::index', ['title' => 'All Product Categories','categories' => $categories)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was. I was using `robclancy/presenter` package to wrap and render objects in the view. For it, the model had to implement a `PresentableInterface` interface. Implementing the interface required the method to have a `getPresenter` method. I had added the `getPresenter` method in my model, but I forgot to return the presenter from that method. Returning the presenter solved the problem.

The code inside the `getPresenter` method is the code that I forgot to write.

```
public function getPresenter()
{
    return new ProductCategoryPresenter($this);
}
```

Thank you guys for trying to help.